# Database of HFOV+focal length+crop factor, for most cameras and smartphones

Tags: products, sensors, technology

A [photography app](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) wants me to enter my camera's details:

[image: Hugin Camera and Lens data]

I have no idea what these numbers means (I entered the numbers pretty randomly), but I know the brand/model of my camera.

Is there a database that gives these values for most popular cameras/smartphones?

- Horizontal field of view
- Focal length
- Focal length multiplier

The `Load lens data...` button asks for a `.ini` file, so a database of such files would be great too.

- [Lensfun](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lensfun/files/) probably had that but it has not been updated since 2015.
- [PkmX/lensfun-profiles](https://github.com/PkmX/lensfun-profiles) has only 5 lenses/cameras.

Comment: you may have more success asking photo sub: https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there's also data here, but its dated 2010: https://static1.pointsinfocus.com/2010/09/depth-of-field-and-equivalent-lens-calculator/dofcalculator.min_.js

Comment: In the JavaScript file you linked to, are you talking about the `var l=` array towards the top? To me it looks like a list of captors, rather than a list of cameras or lenses.

Comment: yeah, but i meant to link to the form too, my bad. https://www.pointsinfocus.com/tools/depth-of-field-and-equivalent-lens-calculator/ that form populates with fov data, i didn't really go through the js file entirely. just did quick swoop, so i could be entirely off here.